# EntityFramwork and WebApi: Issues with complex types

Tags: entity-framework, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I am currently using CodeFirst along and Odata V4 using WebAPI 2.2. It turns out that EF Code first needs all the ComplexTypes to be instantiated before doing any database operations therefore I changed my model classes to instantiate complex type inside constructor of entity. This worked and data got saved in database.

**Issue**:
On Odata the complex type now got serialized with all null values for complex type members. Which I want to avoid from user experience point of view of my APIs.

```
{
    "CorrelationInfo":{
    "ParentIncidentId":null,"CorrelatedCount":0,"LastCorrelatedDate":null
  }
}
```

As you can see in above example odata response all the properties in complex type has default values. But I want this to be exposed as follows.

```
{
   CorrelationInfo:null
}
```

How can resolve this issue? or any alternate approach to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

How about set the CorrelationInfo Nullable, a complex type is Nullable by default, then you just set

```
CorrelationInfo = null
```

instead of

```
new CorrelationInfo()
```

Finally you can get:

```
{
  CorrelationInfo:null
}
```

Hope this can help :)

Comment: As I mentioned above if I set null then code first fails as it needs complex types to be instantiated.

Comment: It is a EF's probleam I think, there are some similar [questions](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/50d33271-c8e3-468f-82e1-7c3178cb4322/complex-types-nullability-convention?forum=adonetefx), if the compelxType is initialized, then you return it to client, OData WebApi is unable to determine whether the complexType is null or not, because user can have a complexType with all default value, if you can do this in Controller's method, before return your class, set CorrelationInfo to null should get the expected response